# SQLSERVER Comparar varios campos de una misma tabla y regresar un valor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Necesito realizar una consulta dentro de mi tabla donde debo comparar los datos ingresados de 3 campos, una vez que se ha comparado, retorne un valor dependiento de si fueron iguales o no.

Ejemplo de mi tabla:

| id_auto | nombre_auto | auto_expediente |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tsuru | 410 |
| 2 | Jetta | 410 |
| 3 | Altima | 410 |

En este caso, al realizar la consulta, deberia retornar un valor como "No Son Iguales"

en cambio si todos los campos concuerdan (ejemplo que todos los campos en **nombre_auto** tuvieran como registro Jetta) debe arrojar un valor como "Todos los autos son iguales"

En mi consulta lo tengo realizado asi, pero al momento de consultar, me arroja los 3 campos con un valor igual o distinto y solo requiero de un solo campo confirmando la igualdad o desigualdad.

Dejo a continuacion mi query que estoy realizando para esto:

```
Select  CASE WHEN nombre_auto =  'jetta' 
             THEN 'Son Iguales' 
             Else 'No Son Iguales' 
             END as Resultado 
      FROM autos 
WHERE auto_expediente = 410
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo que determina si son o no iguales es que la cuenta de las filas que devuelve sea 1 o más.

```
Create table autos
    (id_auto int, 
    nombre_auto varchar(100), 
    auto_Expediente int);
GO
Insert into autos 
    (id_auto, nombre_auto, auto_Expediente)
values
(1,'Tsuru',410),
(2,'Jeta',410),
(3,'Altima',410);
GO
```

Existen muchas opciones para hacer esto. Una que a mi me parece muy didáctica.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (Select nombre_auto
                From autos
                Where auto_Expediente = 410
                group by nombre_auto)
     SELECT CASE
                WHEN Count(*) > 1 THEN 'NO SON IGUALES'
            ELSE 'TODOS LOS AUTOS SON IGUALES'
            END
            FROM CTE;
```

En una tabla de expresión común, cuentas las filas por el criterio que necesitas, y las agrupas por `nombre_auto`.

De la salida de la cte, cuentas y mediante un case devuelves un resultado u otro.

Otra opción también puede ser.

```
SELECT case
           when Count(DISTINCT NOMBRE_AUTO) > 1 
           then 'NO SON IGUALES'
       else 'TODOS LOS AUTOS SON IGUALES'
       END
       FROM AUTOS
       WHERE auto_Expediente = 410;
```

Cuentas mediante un case, si los resultados distintos de la columna son mayores que 1.

[image: result]

Comment: Muchas gracias!, no conocia la sentencia CTE y al investigarla me di cuenta que me puede ayudar muchisimo para futuras consutas similares, te agradezco tu atencion javi!